# React-Router-Dom <Link /> tag is changing URL but not rendering the Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Header Component**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../../asset/crown.svg";

import "./header.scss";
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <Router>
        <Link exact className='logo-container' to='/'>
          <Logo className='logo' />
        </Link>
        <div className='options'>
          <Link className='option' to='/shop'>
            SHOP
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

This is my header Component in which I am using Link tag but these tags are changing the URL in the Search Bar but not actually rendering the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Router inside the Header Component...You can just use Link and then in your App.js setup the Route to the Component. Like So..

App.Js

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../../asset/crown.svg";

import "./header.scss";
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className='header'>
    <ul>
    <li className='logo-container'> 
    <Link  to='/'>
     <Logo className='logo' />
    </Link>
    </li>
<li>   
        <Link to="/shop">
       
         
            SHOP
            </Link>
            </li>
   
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;


//APP COMPONENT

import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";


const App = () => {
  return (
 
      <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component="Home">
      
        
          <Route path="/shop" component="shop">
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to use BrowserRoute inside BrowserRouter.

e.g: when you place a component inside a component it's not JSX there it gets converted to HTML and can cause an error.